# Equation To The Pair Of Angle Bisectors

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the equation to the pair of angle bisectors of the pair of lines $(ax+by)^2=3(bx-ay)^2$.

Efforts:
$$(ax+by)^2=3(bx-ay)^2$$
After simplifying, I got:
$$x^2(a^2-3b^2)+8abxy+y^2(b^2-3a^2)=0$$
Now, what should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the square root on both sides, we obtain
$$ax+by=-\sqrt3(bx-ay) \quad \text{and} \quad ax+by=\sqrt3(bx-ay)$$
and the two lines are
$$
(a+\sqrt3b)x + (b-\sqrt3 a)y = 0\quad\text{and}\quad (a-\sqrt3b)x + (b+\sqrt3 a)y = 0.
$$
The equation for the bisectors is known to be
$$
\frac{|(a+\sqrt3b)x + (b-\sqrt3 a)y|}{\sqrt{(a+\sqrt3b)^2+(b-\sqrt3 a)^2}}=\frac{|(a-\sqrt3b)x + (b+\sqrt3 a)y|}{\sqrt{(a-\sqrt3b)^2+(b+\sqrt3 a)^2}},
$$
which in fact is equivalent to
$$
|(a+\sqrt3b)x + (b-\sqrt3 a)y|=|(a-\sqrt3b)x + (b+\sqrt3 a)y|.
$$
This gives
$$
bx -ay=0
\quad\text{or}\quad
ax + by=0.
$$

Comment: I only got $bx-ay=0$, how did you get $ax+by=0$, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Note that $(a+\sqrt3b)x + (b-\sqrt3 a)y=\pm[(a-\sqrt3b)x + (b+\sqrt3 a)y]$.

Comment: If it is so then why did you take modulus?

Comment: The modulus comes from the original equation. But then you need to solve it, like $|x|=|y|$, which gives $x=y$ or $x=-y$. Just a compact way of writing.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify and try the hard way.
Here's what I will do:
Here:
 $$(ax + by)^2 - 3*(bx − ay)^2 = 0$$
this is of the form $$a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$$
=> the two lines are $$(ax + by + sqrt(3)*bx -sqrt(3)*ay = 0)$$ and 
$$(ax + by -sqrt(3)*bx + sqrt(3)*ay = 0)$$

Comment: That will go well. Except for some particular cases (where some denominators are $0$): Let the slopes be $\tan C$ and $\tan D$. We compute $\tan (C+D)=2 a b/(a^2-b^2)$ ,whence $\tan (C+D)/2\in \{b/a,-a/b\}.$